# DAX: Calculate percentile based on filtered values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table for students with their Name, Gender and TotalScore. I want to caculate 75th percentile for students based on a gender.

[image]

For ex. how do I calculate P75 score for either gender F/M ?

Comment: do you want to know a P75 value? or you want to select Names filtered by gender and P75 value?

Comment: PERCENTILE.EXC(table[Total Score],0.75)

Comment: Just want to get the p75 on the filtered set(based on Gender). For the given table, ex.  get P75 value for F gender only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLANK() values exculdes from calc.

Returns the k-th (exclusive) percentile.
This will return a value based on your slicers or filters.

```
ifGenderSlicerExcl = PERCENTILE.EXC(tableName[Total Score],0.75)
```

This will return only for F.

```
Only F excl=
    CALCULATE(
         PERCENTILE.EXC(tableName[Total Score],0.75)
        ,tableName[Gender]="F"
    )
```

Returns the k-th (inclusive) percentile

```
ifGenderSlicerIncl = PERCENTILE.INC(tableName[Total Score],0.75)
```

This will return only for F.

```
Only F incl=
    CALCULATE(
         PERCENTILE.INC(tableName[Total Score],0.75)
        ,tableName[Gender]="F"
    )
```

You can also add a P slicer in this case change 0.75 to a variable name